# Unity 2D trouble with my randomiser script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, unity3d-2dtools

[image: This image is of the what the screen looks like at the start, I would like these to appear one by one.]

I have created this script to spawn my buttons randomly but do not know how to alter the times they individually spawn as they all spawn at the same time. I can't see them and have not spawned however in the Hierarchy they are being created.

```
Public class RandomSpawn: MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject prefab1, prefab2, prefab3, prefab4, prefab5;

    public float spawnRate = 2f;

    float nextSpawn = 0f;

    int whatToSpawn;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

        if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
        {
            whatToSpawn = Random.Range(1, 6);

            switch (whatToSpawn)
            {
                case 1:
                    Instantiate(prefab1, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Instantiate(prefab2, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Instantiate(prefab3, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Instantiate(prefab4, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Instantiate(prefab5, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
            }

            nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
        }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I’d suggest using coroutines for this, since reading Time.time every frame is not recommended by the docs.

Comment: Brilliant I'll look into that now.

Comment: `_t += Time.time;  if(_t > spawnRate) {//... _t = 0; }`  Try this ?

Comment: Tim Chang, I'm not sure what the  '_t' means, sorry... Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Time.deltaTime` value ,
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

```
private float _t = 0;
private SpawnRate = 2;
void Update() {
            _t += Time.deltaTime;
            if (_t > SpawnRate)
            {
                whatToSpawn = Random.Range(1, 6);

                switch (whatToSpawn)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Instantiate(prefab1, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Instantiate(prefab2, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Instantiate(prefab3, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Instantiate(prefab4, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Instantiate(prefab5, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                        break;
                }

                _t = 0;
            }
```

Comment: Ah okay, I get you, wasn't using the right one, thank you for your help.